# Javascript: Getting the IP of the visitor. I can't access the JSON elements

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I'm trying to read JSON response with JS but I can't find what what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to enbed JS in a plugin I use in WP, but for the moment I'm just trying to get the right information  in a simple HTML file.

This is my code:

HTML

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://ipinfo.io/?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

JS

```
function getIP(json) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += json.ip;
}
```

This what I've tried:

An alert

```
alert('IP address is:' + json.ip);
```

Console

```
console.log(json.city);
```

Parse JSON

```
const obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj.city);
```

I can see the JSON in the console but I just can't access the information. I'm in no way a programmer and I spent many hours trying to figure out this myself and I was unable. The proof, these are the 2 JSFiddle I worked on to find a solution to my problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/cbdj6np3/2/

https://jsfiddle.net/4pqx19ms/1/

Thx,

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p1tqzrdf/ - the function doesn't exist when the script is loaded ... so, define the function before loading the JSONP ... also, the div has to be moved above script, so it exists

Comment: When you're using JSONP you don't need to call `JSON.parse()`. It's already parsed when it calls your function.

Comment: And you're doing things in the wrong order in the fiddle (impossible to tell what your actual code looks like). The div has to exist before the script runs, as does the jsonp callback.

Comment: Thank you guys, I just worked with raw html file and it worked great. I'n feeling embarrassed :(